# Samsung ATIV Book 9 Lite

Tags: 12.04, installation, command-line, gui, samsung

I'm thinking of replacing Win 8 with ubuntu and I have booted from a flash drive, as well as trying from a dvd drive, selecting the try option instead of install. I get the ubuntu loading screen however, from this I get a command prompt style environment, this does not happen with my desktop. Help please!

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the BIOS to "UEFI and CMS OS" instead of "UEFI OS" ?

When booting, press the F2 key and go to the "Boot" menu, and change this option.

It seemed to do the trick for me when I came across the same issue on the same laptop.